# How can i make nodes that are constantly re-rendering change colors for a flash effect at a timed interval for a given number of times in canvas js?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, canvas

I'm simulating a display of nodes on a network using JavaScript canvas. What I'm trying to do is create a function that starts a subprocess independent of the `requestAnimationFrame(animate)` loop, but the problem is that the subprocess should be initiated within the scope of the animation loop which calls itself endlessly while the subprocess should only produce a flashing effect that lasts a few seconds.

All of my attempts have resulted in infinite calls even when I set the condition to run only once. The idea would be that when a node receives a message an alert flash would occur.

What I've been trying to do is to have it console log `'async'` the given 6 times at the specified interval, but it just logs it endlessly.

```
function init(){
    const network = new Network(50)
    network.setCollection()
    
    const animate = function(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
        network.renderNodes()
        window.requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    }
    
    animate(network)
}
```

```
renderNodes(){
    const nodes = this.collection;
    for(const {id,x,y} of nodes){
        const nest = new Nest(x,y,5)
        nest.draw()
        nest.flash()
    }
}
```

```
flash(){
    const action = (count)=>{
        if(count===6) return;
        window.setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log('async')
            action(count+1)
        },500)
    }
    if(!this.done){
        window.setTimeout( ()=>{action(1)})
    }
    this.done = true
}
```

I thought that trying to make sure it only runs once and starting an async process would do the trick but now I don't know what else to do. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Creating a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here would go a long way in helping us better understand the issue.

Comment: Don't call `flash()` during `renderNodes()` which you are calling during every `animate()` frame. As you say, the flashing should be independent from the animation frame loop.